# Sale of property in India purchased earlier using US funds and repatriate now to US

Tags: united-states, india, non-resident, capital-gain, dtaa

I was Non Resident Indians, purchased property in India with funds earned in USA. The funds were transferred from my US account to my In-Laws Bank Account in India.

I am now US Citizen. I am in the process of selling the property and bringing the funds back to USA.

Since, the conversions rates were vastly different compared to 10 years ago, although the property has appreciated in Rupee terms; it is still at loss in dollars terms due to the exchange rate.

What kinds of taxes on both ends are we liable for?

Comment: How was the funds transferred from US to India, was via the NRE account? Has the property appreciated in rupee terms. Do you still hold the NRE account. Please confirm if you are PIO.

Comment: Dheer - No, NRE was not used.  It was wired from my account to my in-laws account in order to make the purchase in 2006. I have documents on that. The property has appreciated in terms of ruppees. I am not PIO. Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: Is the property in your name or your MILs name?

Comment: It's in our names

Comment: You would need to edit the question and include details like who made the transfer, was the transfer to an individual when you say in-laws or only father in law or mother in law? When you say property is in our names? Who is the other person? A foreign national can't buy property in India. https://m.rbi.org.in//scripts/FAQView.aspx?Id=33. So it is surprising you have it in your name when you are not a person of Indian Origin.

Comment: Good point, we were indian citizens when we bought this almost 12 years ago.  Edited the question for better clarity.

Comment: PIO (Person of Indian Origin)  is a _status_ that a person who once held Indian citizenship (but now has a different nationality) acquires when the person changed nationality. (children and grandchlldren of such persons are also considered to be PIOs). Once upon a time, the Government of India was charging PIOs  a large sum (more than $1000, I believe) to get a PIO _card_ officially certifying ther status as a PIO.  This has now been replaced by the OCI (Overseas Citizen of India) card which functions as an automatic visa but whether or not the OP has a PIO or OCI _card_ or not; he is a PIO.